# Initialize Model w Foreign Keys in Django

Tags: python, django, model

I have a Model that represents a card. A card will only ever have two card faces, the front and the back. The card faces contain a background image, with a number of related data fields containing strings and positions to render the strings on it. I want to have the base image as a file and then render the strings onto it so I can print them out through a printer.

I've done DB modelling before but I don't consider myself an expert. I also tend to overthink things so I might just be driving myself crazy when there's a simple solution to do what I want. My googleFu is mostly just leading me around in circles.

I want to prevent anyone from trying to add or delete the card faces. I also want to pre-populate the object so that it only ever has a front and back. The relationship for Card to CardFace is one to exactly two. But I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to do this model.

I've actually got the rendering part working. It's more a matter of when it should be done. I want to save the original unchanged background image so it can be recalled, and then perform the renderings I guess post save? I tried overriding the save method of the objects but only some of the data is accessible through the self reference. Presumably because it hasn't been saved yet.

```
class ItemCardFaceType(IntEnum):
    front = 0,
    back = 1,

    @classmethod
    def choices(cls):
        return [(key.value, key.name) for key in cls]


class CardData(models.Model):
    x_pos = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False, default=0)
    y_pos = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False, default=0)
    data = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, default='', max_length=255)
    word_wrap = models.BooleanField(blank=False, null=False, default=True)
    font = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, default='', max_length=255)
    font_size = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False, default=10)
    card_link = models.ForeignKey('CardFace', blank=False, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Card Data"

class CardFace(models.Model):
    background = models.ImageField(upload_to='card_faces')
    rendered_card = models.ImageField()
    face_type = models.IntegerField(choices=ItemCardFaceType.choices(), default=ItemCardFaceType.front, blank=False, null=False)
    card_link = models.ForeignKey('Card', blank=False, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='item_card')
    card_data = models.ForeignKey(CardData, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Card(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
    width_mm = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False, default=90)
    height_mm = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False, default=50)
    card_faces = models.ForeignKey(CardFace, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='card_front_pictures')
```

Basically I want to take the image on the card, and write some strings on it in certain locations. That part I actually have mostly working.

So I have three questions:

- How do I prepopulate the card so that it only ever has two sides.
- How do I prevent people from trying to add additional sides or delete sides.
- What method should I override to ensure that the rendering is done once all the data is actually IN the objects but before it is written to the DB and disk?

Hopefully I'm making sense here.

Thanks in advance for the kick in the right direction
EK